# None of my buttons/spinners clicking

Tags: android

I doubt I've done any typo but about 10 minutes ago all my buttons would press and do what it is suppose to, but now when I press them it does nothing. I can't even click my spinner to open. I tried deleting the app from my phone and restarting but it still wouldn't work and I'm 99% sure I didn't make any significant changes to make my app not work.

create.java

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button buttontest;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    private ArrayList<Spinner> mSpinners;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);

        mLinearLayout.addView(makeSpinner());    // First spinner

        Button duplicateSpinner = findViewById(R.id.bt_duplicate); //button to duplicate spinner
        duplicateSpinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();//  this makes spinner from the private Spinner code below. so you just need to do the same for the frame layout? put everything in one layout oand do that.
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner);      // Add another spinner

            }
        });

        Button getSpinner = findViewById(R.id.bt_getSpinner);
        getSpinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                for (int i = 0; i < mSpinners.size(); i++) {      // Read all spinners
                    Spinner spinner = mSpinners.get(i);
                    Log.i("TAG", spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Spinner makeSpinner() { //how to make spinners
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }




    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    } }
```

mylistadapter code

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    int groupid;
    List<String> items;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, List<String> items) {
        super(context, vg, id, (List<String>) items);
        this.context = context;
        groupid = vg;
        this.items = items;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textid;
        public TextView textname;

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        {





            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
                viewHolder.textname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            // Fill data in the drop down.
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            String row = items.get(position);
            //holder.textid.setText(row[0]); prints aisle number, dont need

            holder.textname.setText(row);


            return rowView;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I know this might sound obvious but check your button ids match. If they are found on your activity the next step is to check if your click event is being triggered using the debugger. If all else fails try wrapping parts of your  code in a try catch to see if any exceptions are being thrown you might have missed.

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but it actually turned out to be a problem with my xml code which in which I had added some odd variables.  Solved now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a problem with the xml code, I put the element in a layout instead of outside a layout